# Converting a root of a principal quintic to a root of the corresponding general quintic

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, radicals, quintics

I'm working on an implementation of a numeric solver for quintic equations and have a question regarding usage of the principal form.

Say you have some quintic equation in general form. For example, the following:

$$x^5 + 2x^4 + 3x^3 + 4x^2 + 5x + 6 = 0\tag{1}$$

Converting to the principal form via a quadratic Tschirnhausen transformation, we end up with

$$y^5 - 14y^2 - 105y - 126 = 0\tag{2}$$

which has an approximate real root of $\alpha = 3.71725922555816$.

To turn this root into an approximate root of the original quintic we must solve
$$ y=x^2+mx+n\tag{3}$$
for $x$ given $y=\alpha, m = 1, n = 0$, yielding $x = -1.49179798813990$ and $x = 2.49179798813990$, of which the former is indeed an approximate root of the general quintic $(1)$.

My question is how can I determine which root of $(3)$ will be a root of $(1)$ without simply plugging into $(1)$ and testing?

Comment: If you have managed to go that far, what is the harm in plugging in the value and testing?

Comment: no harm as it will only happen once per root so time is not an issue. I just was curious if there was a simple test over y,m,n that tells me which is the root i want, like a determinant. Basically a function to give me a 1 or -1 to multiply the sqrt by in the quadratic formula.